# Django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for type integer: "Build"

Tags: python, django, npm

I have thee model class, with manytomany field, and i use postegresql as base, problem is when I migrate my models terminal shows :

how can i fix it ?

```
    File "C:\Users\zura\Desktop\personalization\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\zura\Desktop\personalization\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\zura\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\zura\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\zura\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute      
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for type integer: "Build"
```

Code:

```
    class Person(models.Model): 
         name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
         def __str__(self):
             return self.fullname
    class Features(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
        feature = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Enrollment')
        def __str__(self):
           return self.name 
    class Enrollment(models.Model):
         person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
         job = models.ForeignKey(Features, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)    
         def __str__(self):
             return self.person.fullname
```

Comment: Yes, I know but still dont working

Answer (score 0):

I think have a couple issues,

- `Person` does not have `fullname` property
- In `Enrollment` model you are declaring that the relations to `Person` and `Feature` can be `None`, this is wrong. Think it like this, it can only exist as a relation between `Person` and `Feature`, is the extra information in the relation, if one or the other not exist then the relation does not exist, so it can not be `None`